# Stata 17 table - show levels with frequency=0

Tags: stata

I am using the new table command in Stata 17 to create a frequency table of a factor variable using fvfrequency and fvpercent. Some possible levels of the factor have 0 frequency, so are not appearing in the table, but I would like to still show a row for those levels. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `fre` from SSC can do this I think.

Comment: This desire makes sense for you, but the question for Stata is how is it supposed to know what might exist in the dataset but doesn't, yet you still care about it? The key is sometimes that a value label has been defined, which is what `fre` exploits. There are other answers, such as `tabcount` and `countvalues` from SSC. I don't know `table` in 17 well enough to give an answer in its terms.  Other people may have something to say.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, it is good to know about `fre` but I am particularly interested in whether this can be done with `table` for the flexibility and formatting/exporting options. I had in mind either using the value labels or explicitly listing the levels somehow

Comment: Sure; that is why I commented and did not answer.